# Usage of 'race' in French

Tags: usage, société

[Wikipedia stunt double's lemma states:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunt_double)

> The work of stunt doubles in American TV and film productions is overwhelmingly taken by white men. (...) When they are made up to look like another race, the practice is called a "paint down".

> Le travail de cascadeurs dans les productions télévisuelles et cinématographiques américaines est massivement pris par les hommes blancs. (...) Lorsqu'ils sont maquillés pour ressembler à une autre race, la pratique s'appelle « paint down ».

The word race, in this context (i.e. designing people of different color/different ethnic group), is acceptable in French? If the answer is negative (as I assume), how someone would convey wiki's text quoted above?

Comment: @jlliagre  I've read the question. It is closely related of course. My question differs slightly. It asks if the word 'race' is acceptable in French? I think that the answer is no but I want to verify it. With this mind, how someone would convey in French wiki's text quoted in the question? (Thanks!)

Comment: @jlliagre I edited my question. I think it differentiates (slightly) for the linked question.

Comment: Le mot « race » ne peut pas être officiellement utilisé en France lorsqu'on parle d'êtres humains. Il ne peut s'appliquer qu'à des animaux (non humains).

Comment: @Toto: I was quite sure from what I have read so far from French wiki pages and my experience. So how could convey a passage like the quoted one in French? Should one use 'des différents groupes ethniques/des différentes ethnicités' or avoid altogether speaking in Metropolitan French for things like this?

Comment: @Dimitris: In the context of the question I'd use “Lorsqu'ils sont maquillés pour ressembler à une personne de couleur”.

Comment: @Toto Un autre point de vue: [Qui est vraiment l'homme de couleur?](https://dessinemoiunehistoire.net/poesie-qui-est-vraiment-l-homme-de-couleur/) On pourra arguer que l'auteur se veut mordant et controversé, il demeure que son argumentation est cohérente.

Comment: @Pasunclue: Tout à fait. Cela reste néanmoins “politiquement” (voire légalement) correct de dire « Homme de couleur » plutôt que *Race noire/jaune/rouge...*